# got bus error when writing to mmap'ed file

Tags: c, linux, mmap

Trying to use mmap to write to a file. Unfortunately the first write in the loop `map[i] = i;` will cause a bus error. Not sure why.

The PC runs Ubuntu 14.04 and the file `/tmp/mmapped.bin` has 12 bytes and the program is invoked with `./a.out 3`.

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define FILEPATH "/tmp/mmapped.bin"
//#define NUMINTS  (1000)
#define FILESIZE 0x400000000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int fd;
    int *map;  /* mmapped array of int's */
    int size = atoi(argv[1]);
    fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDWR| O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("Error opening file for reading");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    map = mmap(0, 4 * size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= size; ++i) {
        map[i] = i;
    }

    if (munmap(map, FILESIZE) == -1) {
        perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `open(FILEPATH, O_RDWR| O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);` truncates your file to zero-length. `mmap` won't extend a file in order to create the mapping; you need to extend the file yourself before you `mmap` it. Also, zero-length mappings are valid, so you don't get a mapping failure, but there is no part of the resulting mapping that you have permission to write to.

Comment: Thanks @twalberg for pointing out the truncation.  I removed the flag `O_TRUNC` (recompiled it) and made sure the file has 12 bytes and `./a.out 3` still gave the bus error.

Comment: Also, since you declare `map` as `int *`, `map[3]` is probably either 12 bytes into the file (32-bit `int`) or 24 bytes into the file (64-bit). In either case, it's beyond the end of a 12 byte file... Try `unsigned char *map;` instead...

Comment: The funny thing is, it caused crash when it's doing `map[0] = 0`.

Comment: Another issue is that you try to `munmap` a region that is considerably larger than what you `mmap`. When I insert a `ftruncate` call before the `mmap` to make sure the file is of sufficient size, and fix the `munmap` call, I no longer get a failure...

Comment: Thanks @twalberg for your answers. I tried removing the flags `O_CREAT|O_TRUNC` in the call to `open()` and it worked as expected.  Please write it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c you need to start at index 0. Because it will simply increment the pointer by the amount `i` and then dereference it. Your code dereferences the pointer beyond the allowed bound.

It should be,

```
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    map[i] = i;
}
```

because it's equivalent to

```
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    *(map + i) = i;
}
```

Also, use

```
map = mmap(0, size * sizeof *map, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

to ensure that enough space is allocated and that `*(map + i)` will be inside bounds. Don't use magic numbers.

Comment: You are right it should have start with `i=0`, but it should not have crashed when `i=1`.  I made the change but it still crashes for Bus Error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`mmap` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) a bus error (`SIGBUS`) happens when you read/write outside the bounds of the file.

The length of the mapping is separate from the length of the file. If your file is newly created its size will be 0, even if you specify a length with mmap. Resize the file with `ftruncate` after opening it.

Comment: Thanks @matthew-marshall for the tip of `ftruncate`. In my case, I have a file with 12 bytes and I just want to overwrite the first 4 bytes.  Any idea why it didn't work?